# Where is this Regex expression not closed in sed (apostrophe parenthesis)?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to update some setting for wordpress and I need to use `sed`.  When I run the below command, it seems to think the line is not finished.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ sed -i 's/define\( \'DB_NAME\', \'database_name_here\' \);/define\( \'DB_NAME\', \'wordpress\' \);/g' /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/wp-settings.php
> ^C
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, using single quotes around the script of a `sed` script is sensible.  This is a case where double quotes would be a better choice — there are no shell metacharacters other than single quotes in the `sed` script:

```
sed -e "s/define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );/define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );/g" /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/wp-settings.php
```

or:

```
sed -e "s/\(define( 'DB_NAME', '\)database_name_here' );/\1wordpress' );/g" /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/wp-settings.php
```

or even:

```
sed -e "/define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );/s/database_name_here/wordpress/g" /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/wp-settings.php
```

One other option to consider is using `sed`'s `-f` option to provide the script as a file.  That saves you from having to escape the script contents from the shell.  The downside may be that you have to create the file, run `sed` using it, and then remove the file.  It is likely that's too painful for the current task, but it can be sensible — it can certainly make life easier when you don't have to worry about shell escapes.

I'm not convinced the `g` (global replace) option is relevant; how many single lines are you going to find in the settings file containing two independent `define DB_NAME` operations with the default value?

You can add the `-i` option when you've got the basic code working.  Do note that if you might ever work on macOS or a BSD-based system, you'll need to provide a suffix as an extra argument to the `-i` option (e.g. `-i ''` for a null suffix or no backup; or `-i.bak` to be able to work reliably on both Linux (or, more accurately, with GNU `sed`) and macOS and BSD (or, more accurately, with BSD `sed`).  Appealing to POSIX is no help; it doesn't support an overwrite option.

Test case (first example):

```
$ echo "define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );" |
> sed -e "s/\(define( 'DB_NAME', '\)database_name_here' );/\1wordpress' );/g" 
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );
$
```

If the spacing around `'DB_NAME'` is not consistent, then you'd end up with more verbose regular expressions, using `[[:space:]]*` in lieu of blanks, and you'd find the third alternative better than the others, but the second could capture both the leading and trailing contexts and use both captures in the replacement.

**Parting words**: this technique works this time because the patterns don't involve shell metacharacters like `$` or  `` ` `` .  Very often, the script does need to match those, and then using mainly single quotes around the script argument is sensible.  Tackling a different task — replace `$DB_NAME` in the input with the value of the shell variable `$DB_NAME` (leaving `$DB_NAMEORHOST` unchanged):

```
sed -e 's/$DB_NAME\([^[:alnum:]]\)/'"$DB_NAME"'\1/'
```

There are three separate shell strings, all concatenated with no spaces.  The first is single-quoted and contains the `s/…/` part of a `s/…/…/` command; the second is `"$DB_NAME"`, the value of the shell variable, double-quoted so that if the value of `$DB_NAME` is 'autonomous vehicle recording', you still have a single argument to `sed`; the third is the `'\1/'` part, which puts back whatever character followed `$DB_NAME` in the input text (with the observation that if `$DB_NAME` could appear at the end of an input line, this would not match it).

Most regexes do fuzzy matching; you have to consider variations on what might be in the input to determine how hard your regular expressions have to work to identify the material accurately.

Comment: Thanks for your help this was very enlightening.  I have two follow up questions for you.  First, it sounds like the `"` approach only works when there are no meta characters other than `'`, essentially something for when I just getting around inputs with sed, not regex.  Second, I'm trying to automate a wordpress setup and one thing I have to do is another `sed` replacement for something like `define('AUTH_KEY',         'LZb|!m$dG,>0/s% UvSqj@MD})HexA-0I|onN[(?H&ETa L|kPkD?<Zb;i~Y).0A');`, is there a clear cut way to escape the meta characters?  Thanks.

Comment: The choice of single vs double quotes has to be made on a case-by-case basis, or you decide to always use single quotes and then when a single quote is needed, you type `'…'\''…'` (the `'\''` sequence ending the current single quoted string, adding a literal single quote, and starting a new single quoted string).  That's what [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) suggests in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985401/15168), and it is fairly simple and reliable — as long as you don't need to interpolate a shell variable.

Comment: If you need to interpolate shell variables, you have to watch for the delimiter in the `s///` command appearing in the shell variable; that will confuse `sed`.  One way around that is to change the delimiter from `/` to another character.  `%` is a common choice, but with your `AUTH_KEY` example, the set of characters used seems to be rather extensive (both `/` and `%` appear).  In such cases, a good standby is a control character — `^A` and `^G` are two common choices.  So, you'd type `s^A…^Adefine('AUTH_KEY', 'LZb|!m$dG,>0/s% UvSqj@MD})HexA-0I|onN[(?H&ETa L|kPkD?<Zb;i~Y).0A')^A` …

Comment: … where the `^A` is a single control character, not a double printing character.  This assumes you know that `^A` won't appear in matching or replacement text.  If you can't determine the alphabet, then you have to take steps to replace the embedded delimiter characters with backslash-delimiter — so `s/…\/abc\/…/…\/def\/…/` to replace `/abc/` by `/def/`.  This is fiddly, though doable in Bash.

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes in most shells don't support any escaping. If you want to include a single quote, you need to close the single quotes and add the single quote - either in double quotes, or backslashed:

```
 sed 's/define\( '\''DB_NAME'\'', '\''database_name_here'\'' \);/define\( '\''DB_NAME'\'', '\''wordpress'\'' \);/g'
```

I fear it still wouldn't work for you, as `\(` is special in sed. You probably want just a simple `(` instead.

```
sed 's/define( '\''DB_NAME'\'', '\''database_name_here'\'' );/define( '\''DB_NAME'\'', '\''wordpress'\'' );/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/define( '"'"'DB_NAME'"'"', '"'"'database_name_here'"'"' );/define( '"'"'DB_NAME'"'"', '"'"'wordpress'"'"' );/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried this but it just ran forever and didn't finish :(